# Callback closure function not working in cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, closures, uialertcontroller

I have a tableview cell which contains a specific button for showing alert sheet.
I've learned that button itself can't be pressed inside of table view cell. It must be called from a view controller.
So I`ve added a callback closure like so:

```
class FeedViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var callback : (() -> ())?
    static let reuseIdentifier: String = "FeedTableViewCell" 

    lazy var menuButton: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        return btn
    }()

 override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        addSubview(menuButton)

        }

    @objc func menuTapped() {
       print("menu tapped")
       callback?()
    }
```

I suspect it might be a problem with table view cell registration.. Pls let me know if that's not it. And in the view controller I did this:

```
class FeedViewController: UIViewController {
// some code...

  tableView.register(FeedViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: FeedViewCell.reuseIdentifier)

}

extension FeedViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: FeedViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FeedViewCell
        cell.callback = {
            
            print("menu")
            let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            
            actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: { action in
                print("tap dismiss")
            }))
            
            actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Follow", style: .default, handler: { action in
                print("tap follow")
            }))
            
            self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

So the main question is, why is the button not working? It doesn't even print "menu"

Thank you for all of your answers

Comment: `lazy var menuButton` that's never going to be initialized, because you never reference `menuButton` or add it as a subview

Comment: Also to prevent strong references you should do `cell.callback = { [weak self] in ` instead of `cell.callback = {`

Comment: I don't see you adding `menuButton` to the cell as a subview? Where did you do that?

Comment: @aheze its actually initialized and its added to the view. I just skipped that part to save up space in the question

Comment: @Russ hmm, ok...

Comment: @Sweeper sorry I just skipped that to save up space in the question. Ive edited it now. Please have a look

Comment: @Russ can you add a `print("menu tapped")` inside `@objc func menuTapped() {`, for testing?

Comment: @aheze Ok, i've aded it. And it doesn't print anything. When I press the button, the cell becomes grey as if I clicked the whole cell (didselectrowat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong.

```
addSubview(menuButton)
```

Instead:

```
contentView.addSubview(menuButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your button into cell's content view like this:
`self.contentView.addSubview(self.menuButton)`